# External Storage (public across apps)

Tags: java, android

I need to make a file in the Android External Storage area that can be accessed (read/write) by other apps.
I looked [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory%28java.lang.String%29) but that says to pass it a directory type such as DIRECTORY_MUSIC, DIRECTORY_PICTURES etc.
But none of those types is what i want. So what I'm thinking is this:

```
File F = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "MyAppName" + File.separator + "MyFile");
```

Will this work or how can i ensure that a file will truly have public read/write access for other apps?
Also, I read somewhere that OutputStreams are only supposed to take a name with no path, and are always private, so how would i read/write ints to `F`?

Comment: It is convention to accept an answer if any of them helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems to me that the statement for creating a new File you have there, would work. Although, why not try it out? Also, it is absolutely possible to write to a file and have it be accessible publicly, you do not need to do anything for this to happen, it will just happen by default. Reading/writing ints from/to the File can be done as usual, I recommend converting it to a String before writing.

Answer (score 0):

It will works. You can ensure that a file truly have public access if you'll find it with some file manager and try to open it. In your example path to your file will be "%HOME_DIR%\MyAppName\MyFile". Also for creating file you could use [FileOutputStream](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FileOutputStream.html) (not OutputStream), it takes File as parameter in constructor.

Comment: thanks but what i really need is writing ints to the file, preferably a function `FileWriteInt(int line, int data)` that writes `data` on line `line`.

Comment: You could use [DataOutputStream](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/DataOutputStream.html) . DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(yourFile));
    out.writeInt(yourInt);

Answer (score 0):

Files created in external storage are by default can be accessed by any other app (since the file is in external storage). The only thing you can control is the lifetime of the created file. As in whether the file should exist with your app only and deleted once the app is uninstalled or the file exists even after your app is removed.

If you want to create a file on your own path (not in DIRECTORY_PICTURE etc) inside your application then use getExternalFileDir() and pass null to it. See the link below for more details.

[Saving file in external storage](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html)